# When having mulitple Y lines data, how can I let the chart automatically scale to show them all?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I have a linechart with multiple lines (the number is dynamic) and I would need to always scale the Y so that all lines are shown - so the scale should always be based on the range with highest values. Is there a way how to it automatically? I found some example with automatic yScaling using d3.max but that is done for a known dataset. In my case, I do not know what range will be the one to use.

Comment: deleting your identical question of less then a few days ago and creating it again (up-phoning your ad on ebay) usually doesn't result in getting an answer

Comment: @rioV8 It was not the same, I learned a lot of things that allowed me to be more precise. But I still feel I did not formulate it properly because such a feature must be very basic.

Comment: Would be a lot easier to help you if you could post some code.